# Multiple servers with one domain name?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, iis, web-hosting

I have an old ASP.NET Server and Website running in IIS on this surver with many sub sites and pages for example:

www.mysite.com/users/

www.mysite.com/tools/

www.mysite.com/orders/vieworders.aspx

I now have a new website that will be running on a new Apache server that I will be transering my domain to (for example)

www.mysite.com/index.php

I would like my new site (with my old domain) to still direct traffic to the old pages on my IIS server, is there a way to do this?  So for example if someone visits www.mysite.com they would go to my PHP site, but if they type in, or used a book mark to www.mysite.com/orders/vieworders.aspx they would end up at my old site on IIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could set up your Apache webserver as a Reverse Proxy which could funnel requests to your old ASP.NET web server should the client hit any of your 'legacy' sub directories.

Have a look at [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) for Apache.